# Customize attribute rowsPerPageTemplate of <p:dataTAble>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In my application I have a `<p:dataTable>` with attributes `lazy="true" paginatorTemplate="...{RowsPerPageDropdown}..." rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100"`
I set value attribute of this datatable from a lazyDataModel. I got total no of records of this dataModel by `dataModelName.getRowCount()` .

Now problem is I want to show `rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,ALL"` where `ALL` stands for total no of records of dataModel `(ie. dataModelName.getRowCount())`.

If anyone know this please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You try: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15481

Comment: @RongNK:Thanks for reply It works that means it shows number of records. But I want to display `All` in place of number. can you tell how it can be done?

Comment: I think you can, i will try now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is change to ALL in clientside by using jquery or javascript.
I have one form(`id="form"`) and one datatable(`id="cars"`) inside(you try the link [ALL](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15481) first):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#form\\:cars .ui-paginator-rpp-options.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-left')
                    .each(function() {
                        $(this).children().last().html('ALL');
                    });
                })
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rowsPerPageTemplate="8,16,{ShowAll|'All'}"
```