# Primefaces paginator, how to display 'ViewAll' option in rowsPerPageTemplate

Tags: primefaces, pagination

In Primefaces paginator, in rowsPerPageTemplate how to display View All, which will load all the data in the page.
The following link has a solution but, it is working only on page load.
When a certain action takes place and updates the datatable content the View All is not displayed anymore. 
[Customize attribute rowsPerPageTemplate of <p:dataTAble>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805516/customize-attribute-rowsperpagetemplate-of-pdatatable/28075145#28075145)

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

simply apply the javascript in the link you posted again after actions that update the table. E.g. via something like `oncomplete="addViewAll()"` attribute

```
function addViewAll() {
     $('#form\\:cars .ui-paginator-rpp-options.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-left')
                .each(function() {
                    $(this).children().last().html('ALL');
                });
}
```