# Customize the displayed value in Primefaces <p:dataTable> rowsPerPageTemplate for the all option ("Show All" instead of "*")

Tags: javascript, primefaces, xhtml

I have an issue with the primefaces dataTable. I know that I am able to show all entries of my dataTable by using * as a value for the rowsPerPageTemplate option. This works fine so far. The only problem for me is that it gets also displayed as * in the browser. My question is how can I change this displayed value to another String. For example "Show All"? 
I already tried a few things but it didn't work out for me so far. 
Here is the important part of my actual xtml code.

```
    <h:form id="eqTableForm">
        <p:dataTable var="pm" value="#{eqbean.filteredEquipment}" rowKey="#{pm.equipmentNumber}" paginator="true" rows="20"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="20,40,60,*" selection="#{eqbean.selectedEqs}" id="pmsTable" emptyMessage="#{i18n.pmoverview_pmtableempty}">             

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

            <p:column filterBy="#{pm.equipmentDescription}"   
                      headerText="#{i18n.pmoverview_pmtablefilter2}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{pm.equipmentDescription}" />  
            </p:column>
            <p:column filterBy="#{pm.customerDetailsIdentNumber}"   
                      headerText="#{i18n.pmoverview_dialogcustidentnr}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{pm.customerDetailsIdentNumber}" />  
            </p:column>    
            <p:column filterBy="#{pm.equipmentNumber}"   
                      headerText="#{i18n.pmoverview_pmtablefilter}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{pm.customerDetailsSerialNumber}" style="color: gray"/>  
            </p:column>  
        </p:dataTable>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#pmsTable .ui-paginator-rpp-options.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-left')
                        .each(function () {
                            $(this).children().last().xhtml('alle');
                        });
            });
        </script> -->
    </h:form>
```

The stuff which is commended out, is something I already tried but it doesn't work for me.
I found it here: [Customize attribute rowsPerPageTemplate of <p:dataTAble>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805516/customize-attribute-rowsperpagetemplate-of-pdatatable)

Has anyone another idea or could tell me what I got wrong about it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error about `Cannot find component for expression ":content:pmsTable" referenced from "content:btnSubmit".` is in no way related to the title and text of the question or the javascript of your 'attempt'. Try solving this separately.  And the selector in your javasrcipt is weird. You use a widgetvar value in there instead of an id.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answare. It's Strange. Because the error only occurs when I comment the JavaScript back in.  And yes of course I use the id "pmsTable" instead of the widgetVar. I am going to edit this. I posted an old code piece. Sorry for that.

Comment: The main point is I just want to know how to change the displayed value from * to anything else. While not losing the functionality of it. :)

Comment: @Kukeltje You are completely correct the error definitly not comes from the thing I ask for and has nothing to do with my main issue. I found out what it was. It was just the <h:form> I build around my dataTable. Because of it some other parts of the code could not find it anymore. I am going edit it and leave out of my question. Again sorry for the confusion.